# Fetch profiles from OpenID / Facebook / Twitter /Google Accounts

Tags: php, openid, profile

Im developing kind of authentication and profiling system and i would like to provide a service users to migrate their profiles from thier `OpenID` , `Facebook` , `Twitter` and `Google accounts`

Is it possible to fetch data from these accounts such as **name , DOB , Location** and how to fetch using PHP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write an applications in this services using theirs API.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

https://dev.twitter.com/docs

http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/accounts/